# How to disable author query in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, security, wordpress-theming

In wordpress, when you hit url like the following:

http://www.example.com/?author=1

If the author ID is valid then they will be redirected to the author URL, for example:

http://www.example.com/author/username

Then the hacker start attacking the username. How could I disable (?auther=xx) query in url?

for example redirect the request to another page like 404 (not found) page

Comment: Make a 301 redirect to your home page?

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182236/completely-remove-the-author-url

Comment: Can you tell a little more about the actual problem. What would a potential hacker do?

Comment: Brute Force Attack or Dictionary Attack

Comment: @Hobo I'm using IIS server

Comment: Fair enough; though the second part of that answer was server-agnostic.  Though it's the same as Prettyfly added below (after my comment).  Sorry it was no help

Answer (score 1):

I believe that dingo-d has it right, above, referring to the 301 redirect.  I have installed 301 redirects on several Wordpress sites to accomplish this.  I redirect `[domain]/?author=*` with a wildcard to my 404 page.   I have watched my activity logs before and after implementing this.   The malicious login attempts immediately switch from valid user names to the generic "admin."

Answer (score 0):

Add the following filter to your functions.php file;

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'disableAuthorUrl');

function disableAuthorUrl(){
    if (is_author())) {
       wp_redirect(home_url());
       exit();
    }
}
```

This will check all incoming requests to see if the page requested is an author page, and if so, redirect to the homepage, or wherever else you choose.

Comment: this method works, but when you inspect elements it do the following: 
1- [domain]/?author=1 =>status code 301
2- [domain]/author/username => status code 302
3- excute the command `wp_redirect(home_url());` status code 200

Comment: Which means hacker still know the author name

Comment: Ah, I guess you'd need to use mod_rewrite rules then, which would be done through .htaccess usually. I'm not familiar enough with IIS to tell you how to do it in web config, but [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) gives a pretty good explanation!